# Displaying multiple equations

Tags: math-mode, equations

I want to display multiple lines of centered equations. Each equation has multiple equalities and inequalities, so aligning is not called for. All I want is display them one line at a time, centered, with not too much space between them. Is the only way to use multiple `\begin{equation}\end{equation}` environments? Surely there must be a more efficient way, but I can't seem to find any way to do this online. Here is an example:

```
$$(a_1,\ldots,a_n)M\subset(a_1,\ldots,a_{n+m})M\subsetneq M,$$
$$(a_{n+1},\ldots,a_{n+m})\frac{M}{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)M}\simeq\frac{(a_1,\ldots,a_{n+m})M}{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)M}\subsetneq\frac{M}{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)M}.$$
```

Comment: Hint: You can replace `\ldots` by `\dots` and let TeX take care of the placement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are already using `amssymb` I hope. Why not look in to the `amsmath` manual (`texdoc amsldoc` from command prompt/line). It provides many environments for typing mathematics. For these two equations, you can use `gather*` (no number).

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,showframe}   %% showframe for demo only
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
(a_1,\ldots,a_n)M\subset(a_1,\ldots,a_{n+m})M\subsetneq M,\\
(a_{n+1},\ldots,a_{n+m})\frac{M}{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)M}\simeq
  \frac{(a_1,\ldots,a_{n+m})M}{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)M}\subsetneq\frac{M}{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)M}.
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have long equations, then you may even prefer `multline` environment. If you use `mathtools` package instead, it will load `amsmath` by itself along with extended macros.